# how call another php file to Codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

how call `.php` outside the folder

my folder structurer is

[image]

I'm in **cart.php**

my code is

```
$tpl_file ='../mail.php';//problem is here LINE 279
$msg_tmpl = file_get_contents($tpl_file);
if (!file_exists($tpl_file))
   {
?>
   <script>
     alert('no');
   </script>
<?php
   }
   else
   {
   ?>
      <script>
         alert('yes');
      </script>
   <?php
 }
```

So my question is I want to get all data from the `mail.php` and assign it `$tpl_file`.

In above try I'm getting always **NO** with

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents(../mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: pages/cart.php
>
> Line Number: 279

any Ideas??

Comment: Where the exact location of mail.php

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948171/how-to-load-a-view-file-from-within-another-view-with-codeigniter-without-having

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$tpl_file ='../mail.php';
```

To

```
$tpl_file ='application/views/pages/mail.php';
```

**NOTE:**
From your screenshot,`mail.php` is located in `application/views/pages/mail.php`

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
$tpl_file ='../mail.php';
```

to

```
$tpl_file =__FILE__.'mail.php';
```

as both files are in the same directory then why relate the path to parent directory

Comment: `file_get_contents(mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: you are in cart.php  right and the cart.php and mail.php are in same folder ?

Comment: OS?? whats purpose of that??

Comment: Just tell me... there are issues with some OS and file permission and try adding application/views/pages/ in your path

Comment: this will not work because in view, codeigniter needs referance from `index.php`, instead `__DIR__.'/mail.php'` will work, -1 sorry

Comment: its ok.. i was trying to help.. and i didnt knew that.. so thanks that will also be helpful to me in future

Answer (score 1):

Try to use full relative path to the file

```
$tpl_file = APPPATH.'views/pages/mail.php';
```

OR Try to Use

```
 $tpl_file = $this->load->view('pages/mail',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter refers file and directories with referance to `index.php` located at root folder of your project.

So, You will get it by

```
$tpl_file = 'application/views/pages/mail.php';
```

or, if both are in same directory,

```
$tpl_file = __DIR__.'/mail.php';
```

But that will be bad idea, instead assign it the Codeigniter way by,

```
$tpl_file = $this->load->view('pages/mail', '', true);
```

So, your final code will be

```
$tpl_file = $this->load->view('pages/mail', '', true);

if ($tpl_file)
{
    // do something
}
```

More info [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code will work for you.

```html
$this->view('mail');
```

Comment: there is another way to load this from controller to. But this will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$msg_tmpl = $this->load->view('mail', '', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using CI, I would recommend using following code:

```
<?php    
    $tmp_file = $this->load->view('pages/mail', array(), TRUE);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `APPPATH` for this

```
$msg_tmpl = file_get_contents(APPPATH.'views/pages/mail.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several way.

**way 1#**

```
$tpl_file =VIEWPATH.'pages/mail.php'
$msg_tmpl = file_get_contents($tpl_file);
```

mail.php is inside your view path so you can get value like this

**way 2#**

```
$msg_tmpl = $this->load->view('pages/mail',null,true);
//this will return the content instead of displaying it output.
```

**Note**

Your all php code runs through main `index.php`.So if you want to use relative path it should be relative with `index.php` not with `cart.php`