# include a common file fails inside only one file Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos

i am including "navigation.php" which has the common menu in all my views .

```
<div id="navigation">
    <? include("navigation.php"); ?>
</div>
```

this code works in every other files but in one file it gives errors .

```
Severity: Warning
Message: include(navigation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: views/readsinvo_index.php
Line Number: 2


Severity: Warning
Message: include(): Failed opening 'navigation.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
Filename: views/readsinvo_index.php
Line Number: 2
```

in "readsinvo_index.php" it is same as the other files

```
<div id="navigation">
    <? include("navigation.php"); ?>
</div>
```

and both the files are inside "views" . both files have permission 777 .

**But when i tried with**

```
<? include(dirname(__FILE__)."/navigation.php"); ?>
```

It works perfectly , but in all other pages , it is working when used

```
<? include("navigation.php"); ?>
```

is there any possible reason that i cannot include the file normally only in this file . I am using codeigniter framework and CentOS .

Comment: Try with `include(APPPATH.'views/navigation.php');`

Comment: Is there any reason for not using CodeIgniter's `$this->load->view();`? You can includes views within views.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus , The project is done by another developer , I am now maintaining it . I will change the code :) . But as i said the problem occurs only in one view , it has no special code. other views are working fine with  <? include("navigation.php"); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `APPPATH`

```
APPPATH.'views/navigation.php'
```

And Possible duplicate of [how call another php file to Codeigniter view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30884251/4595675)

Comment: This works . thank you . Is there any possible  reason that only one view is not working and others are working fine , I know this cannot be recreated ;)

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter runs from a single entry script file `index.php`.

So, when you say current directory, it is the path of `index.php`'s directory.

If you include some file, it will first search for any file existing in the given directory, then in include path.

The statement `<? include(dirname(__FILE__)."/navigation.php"); ?>`

The `dirname` gives you path of `index.php`.

When you add statement: `<? include("/navigation.php"); ?>` in views, it will search for the views directory, hence, the error.

Comment: This works . thank you . Is there any possible  reason that only one view is not working and others are working fine , I know this cannot be recreated ;)